# T-test in head-to-head matchup between nearly identical teams

Tags: t-test, games

Suppose I have a team (Team A) and I am able to make an clone of them (Team B) that is identical except for one difference (for example, they are baseball teams and Team B uses a different type of bat than Team A).

If Team A and Team B play a number of games against each other, can the statistics from the head-to-head games (for example, number of hits by each team, strikeouts, walks, etc.) be compared using a t-test? Otherwise, the games and teams will be identical (same players, same stadiums, teams alternate which team bats first, same pitchers, etc.).

I've been getting conflicting information about whether this is valid since their stats are not against a common opponent (instead head-to-head comparison) so I'm not sure if a t-test is suitable.

Sample Data: Can I use a t-test to see if Team A's hits are statistically significantly different than Team B's hits?

```
 Game # |Team A Hits|Team B Hits

  1     |     5     |     9      

  2     |     4     |     5      

  3     |     7     |     12
```

Comment: I think it depends. Is there an evidence that the team's performance depends on past games? Then there is an autocorrelation. Also, if the team's performance a team depends on the other team's performance, both outcomes are correlated. If both are true, probably you need a test that account for both correlation structures, just my humble 2 cents

Comment: @user3119750 Let's assume that neither team learns from past games, and that both teams are performing at their full potential in each game (so the outcomes depend on which team is better, rather than one team "taking the afternoon off")

Comment: If your assertions hold, independent 2-sample t-test works. But in case they do not, your test results may be false. There are ways to check your assumptions. You can do time-series analysis to see if there are any autocorrelation between the games for each team. If there is none, the paired score must be bivariate normal. In case there is a correlation between the pairs, it's not a big problem since you can use paired t-test.

Comment: @user3119750 I guess my main question is whether I can say they are independent since the performance of A (its score) is dependent on the quality of opponent (Team B), whereas the score of B is dependent on the quality of A (that is, one team may be a better team...which is what we want the t-test to show). Had they both played Team C, it would have been clearer, but I'm unsure since for each game there would be two data point <Team A score with Team B as opponent> and <Team B score with Team A as opponent>, so essentially two factors are changing (team being measured, and opponent).

Comment: If you were to take the difference between the two scores, you will only generate one data point per game, which is the essence of the paired t-test. My only concern is that there is an autocorrelation structure between successive games, which is why I suggested to look at the time-series. I hope I'm making sense and hopefully others can add more